# Suggest data structure for this grid?

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

Suppose you have 3X3 grid which is formed by taking values from any of 2 9x9 grid. I want to save information that what values have been consumed from which 9X9 grid while creating this new 3X3 grid.

Since using a value type as a Dictionary key is problematic as written in xamarin documentation. So I'm using SortedList which works but I would like your opinion what would be the best way to go. Should I use tupple?

```
SortedList<int, SortedList<int, SortedList<int, int>>> foo =
    new SortedList<int, SortedList<int, SortedList<int, int>>>(); 

int grid = 0;
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
int val = 0;

if(!foo.ContainsKey(grid))
 foo.Add(grid,new SortedList<int,SortedList<int, int>>());

if (!foo[grid].ContainsKey(row))
 foo[grid].Add(row, new SortedList<int, int>());

if(!foo[grid][row].ContainsKey(column))
 foo[grid][row].Add(column,val);
```

Comment: If you know exactly how big it's ever going to be, why not just use an array?

Comment: I want to save information that which points of the two 9X9 grids have been consumed while making this new 3X3 grid. So I can use the points left in these 2 9X9 grids to create more unique 3X3 grids.

Comment: by point I mean one box on this grid.

Comment: Why not make a Class for the data? Then you get to give a meaningful name to each property. If you used a Tuple, you would have to remember what each element represents.

Comment: "Xamarin": monotouch, mono, monomac, etc.?

Comment: Yes I'm working on project in unity3d which uses mono.

Comment: Create a class representing your single box with all the properties and populate a 2-dimentional array. This way you can have your array built dynamically and it can be 2x2, 3x3 etc.